# VBA GetPrivateProfileString

Tags: excel, vba, ini

I want to read an INI File with `GetPrivateProfileString`.
The problem is that my string contains some characters that should not be there

[image: Picture]

I think that this issue is coming from `path = String(255,0)` but if I do not write this, my Excel program just stops working.

Is there a way to bypass this problem or is something wrong with my code?

**Sub**

```vb
Dim path as String,m2_path as string
path = String(255, 0)
m2_path = String(255, 0)

nc = GetPrivateProfileString("PATH", "path1", "", path, 255, inipath)
nc = GetPrivateProfileString("PATH", "path2", "", m2_path, 255, inipath)
```

**Function**

```vb
Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
             (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
               ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
               ByVal lpDefault As String, _
               ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
               ByVal nSize As Long, _
               ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
```

**INI file**

```
[PATH]
path1="G:\Arbeit\gen molding"
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value nc tells you how many characters there are in the string.  The problem is the actual interface is a character array: not a string.  So what you have to do is give it your best guess as to how many characters you can possibly get (nsize) and it will tell you how many characters there are.

```
dim path1 as string, path2 as string, path as string

path = string(255, 0)
nc = GetPrivateProfileString("PATH", "path1", "", path, 255, inipath)
path1 = left(path, nc)
nc = GetPrivateProfileString("PATH", "path2", "", m2_path, 255, inipath)
path2 = left(path, nc)
```

Comment: I would advise to use `Len(path)` for the fifth parameter instead of the literal `255` to avoid buffer overflow and the OP's "I do not write this, my Excel program just stops working."